# How to install a specific video driver on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, drivers, video

I need to install a compatible video driver on a Fedora machine.
The resolution proportion isn't very well and I can't change the brightness and contrast (xbacklight and xgamma) either.

Please answer me with a complete solution or a final successfully tutorial.

Some information about the system is:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
$ cat /etc/issue
Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
```

Comment: As Fedora 17 is the most recent I'm sure it has a compatible video driver for Intel graphics. However there are many sources for failure and some are addressed here http://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop . Maybe you can find your solution there.

Comment: @user1129682, first I need to install a compatible driver, to improve the resolution (this is my main problem). And I think this could solve the problem with the brightness and contrast too. Unfortunally this kubuntu cant help me for now.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you'd check whether it's installed or not:

```
$ sudo rpm -q xorg-x11-drv-intel
xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.20.1-1.fc17.x86_64
```

If that's the output, then you'll have to check for other issues in your config. Anyway, if the rpm command doesn't show anything for installing it, the easiest way is using yum for downloading it from online repos:

```
$ sudo yum install xorg-x11-drv-intel
```

Once installed restart you're X server or simply reboot your machine. After the reboot, if resolution is not good check it on Gnome display settings, you'll find it on "Applications -> System settings".

I have to say I've been using Fedora 17 and Kororaa (a Fedora 17 remix) with the same graphic card you've got and had no problem, the driver was installed during installation process and had nothing else for configuring.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

BTW, if you still have problems after checking everything, could you please provide more information about your setup ? Desktop environment, type of installation you did, are you using official Fedora or a Remix?...and so on. Thanks.

Comment: Thx a lot tripledes for help. Unfortunally or fortunally my output is equal of yours and using the yum I got a return saying that is the latest version. I'm using the official Fedora 17 and Dell monitor currently with a wrong resolution of 1280x1024 (dont fit well). My main problem is with the resolution. So, how can I discover the better resolution for this monitor and provide it to use?

Comment: From a terminal console on your gnome session, what does xrandr command returns? BTW, I think this could make for another question as your first one is answered, don't you think? :)

Comment: Yes, I think I can ask about the resolution first. If the problem insn't with the driver. I'll send the gnome output later, but in KDE we have:                  xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024      76.0* 
   1024x768       76.0  
   800x600        73.0  
   640x480        73.0

Comment: Looks like your screen settings are not being well detected...anyway, ask about it but seems you'll have to configure it by hand.