# How to find the best monitor resolution and put it to work? Fedora

Tags: fedora, xorg, drivers, monitors

In this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44859/how-to-install-a-specific-video-driver-on-fedora) I'm asking how to install a compatible driver to a Fedora machine, but, the main problem is a bad resolution.

So, how can I find the best resolution to my monitor and put it to work?

Please answer me with a complete solution or a successfully tutorial.

Some system info is:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

$ cat /etc/issue
Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)

$xandr
 xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024 default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm 1280x1024 76.0* 1024x768 76.0 800x600 73.0 640x480 73.0
```

**Edit**

Looks like the main problema now is this output:

**xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default**

Everything I try stops at this problem with the gamma.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What makes you think that Xorg did not detect your best resolution?

Comment: Because a mac machine on my right side, who has smaller dimensions operates with a bigger resolution. And, because the font isn't good to see and few windows could fit in this huge screen (readable windows). 1280x1024 isn't the resolution to this machine, this is certain. Need to be a bigger one.

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see what resolutions Xorg thinks it has.  Maybe [how to add xrandr resolutions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) will help as well.

Comment: Nice tip. I'll take a look.

Comment: I tried all options in **xrandr --output <Name> --mode 1024x768**, where <Name> coulb be VGA,VGA1,VGA-0,LVDS, LVDS1, TMDS, etc. None works. Returns something like **xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output <Name> not found; ignoring**. What can I do?

Comment: [Let me google that for you...](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=xrandr%3A+Failed+to+get+size+of+gamma+for+output+default+warning%3A+output+%3CName%3E+not+found%3B+ignoring)

Comment: Someone who has the 1920x1080 resolution que can give me the output of **cvt 1920 1080 75**, **cvt 1920 1080 60**, **cvt 1920 1080 59** and **cvt 1920 1080 74**?

Comment: Are you using the right driver? if it's intel a simple "grep intel /var/log/Xorg.0.log" should give you information if it's in use, also "glxinfo | grep OpenGL"

Comment: Today's systems negotiate the best possible resolution on themselves between monitor and graphics card. Seems something in there isn't working right. Check the cable connecting screen and PC, check particularly that there are no bent pins or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xrandr -q` should give you all the possible resolutions supported by your screen (based on current driver). The one that it's currently using will have an asterisk (*) next to it. If it's at the top of the list, it can't get any higher. It's possible that it's using the wrong aspect ratio (a 16:10 resolution on 16:9 monitor, so things would be a bit stretched). That should be as simple as picking a resolution that matches the aspect ratio of your monitor.

Comment: I'm not currently using Fedora (and looks like I will not do it for soon) so I will embrace this answer because it solves the question. Thx adam.